# Creating variable groups in Sass

Tags: css, sass

On the site I'm working on we were using [Scaffold](https://github.com/anthonyshort/Scaffold), which is a PHP-based system similar to Sass. It also can process Sass functions\files. Unfortunately that system is now abandonware, and we are looking on a way to move completely to Sass. There is one big feature with Scaffold though that I'm not finding a way to port to Sass, the variable groups.

Variable in Scaffold can be organized in groups and used with a point-separated markup. For example I would define them as:

```
@variables vargroup1{
    variable1: ####;
    variable2: ####;
    variable3: ####;
    variable4: ####;
}
```

And later use on the code as, for example.

```
body{ width: vargroup1.variable1; margin: vargroup1.variable2 + 10;}
```

This helps development a lot, since you can group together variables from a system and reading the CSS files you can easily know what to reference. I didn't find anything like that on the Sass documentation, anyone knows if it is possible? Or if there is anyway using Mixins to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SASS - get map item value by item index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468351/sass-get-map-item-value-by-item-index)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no equivalent in Sass. But I can think in two workarounds:

**1)** [Sass lists](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists) and its related [list functions](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#list-functions).

Your code could look like the following:

```
$variables = 40px 30px 20px 10px;

body {width: nth($variables, 1); margin: nth($variables, 2) + 10;}
```

It's not the same because list indexes can't be strings, so you haven't any way to name your variables.

**2)** Define a custom function. Look at *Function Directives* section in Sass reference

```
@function variables($variable_name) {
  @if ($variable_name == 'variable1') {
    @return 40px;
  } @else if ($variable_name == 'variable2') {
    @return 30px;
  }
}

body {width: variables('variable_1'); margin: variables('variable_2') + 10;}
```

This way is less intuitive and uglier but you can 'name your variables'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, I feared as much.

Comment: Your are welcome. It's a pity there is no an exact equivalent.

Comment: @WaitingforDev... Can you update this answer that was accepted over a decade ago before [Sass maps](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) existed?

Answer (score 5):

I came across [this somewhat clunky solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sass-lang/upr78cyrW1I) (see Chris Eppstein's reply) using [`zip`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#zip-instance_method) and [`index`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#index-instance_method).  Apparently a maintainer of SASS added these built-in functions in response to a similar question.

To quote his reply:

> ```
> $border-names: a, b, c;
> $border-widths: 1px, 1px, 2px;
> $border-styles: solid, dashed, solid;
> $border-colors: red, green, blue;
> $borders: zip($border-widths, $border-styles, $border-colors);
>
> @function border-for($name) {
>    @return nth($borders, index($border-names, $name))
> }
>
> @each $name in $border-names {
>   .border-#{$name} {
>     border: border-for($name);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Would generate:
>
> ```
> .border-a { border: 1px solid red; }
> .border-b { border: 1px dashed green; }
> .border-c { border: 2px solid blue; }
> ```

The "naming your variables" comes from the list "`-names`" at the top; you then use the `index` of a desired variable name from that variable list to get the nth value from another variable lists.  `zip` is used to mush separate lists together, so that you can retrieve the same index from all lists at the same time.  Wrapping that behavior in a function makes it easier to retrieve a set.

Comment: hmm...multidimensional arrays seem nicer -- see [SASS @each with multiple variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572588/sass-each-with-multiple-variables) and the ["more elegant" solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8380156/1037948)

Comment: wait - zip is making the multidimensional array.  nevermind; I'll leave the link above because it's still useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the scss/sass map function:

```
@use "sass:map";

$variables: (
    "variable1": ####;
    "variable2": ####;
    "variable3": ####;
    "variable4": ####;
}

body {
    width: map.get($variables, "variable1"); 
    margin: map.get($variables, "variable2") + 10;
}
```

[Documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SASS lists a it's related functions on a way similar to that:

```
// List order: top, bottom, left, right, width, height, ...
$Header: 10px,auto,10px,auto,100%,50px;
$Footer: auto,0px,0px,auto,100%,20px;

@function getVar($variable,$name:top){
    $var_index:1;
    @if $name==bottom {
        $var_index:2;
    } @else if $name==left {
        $var_index:3;
    }
    // Continue de if else for each property you want.
    return nth($variable,$var_index);
}
```

That way calling something like:

```
getVar($Header,left)
```

Should return the value of the left property for the list of `Header`, but changing it to `getVar($Footer,top)` would return the value for the top property of the "Footer Group" (Footer List of Values).

That works for the time of using the values, but a the definition, you must follow the exact order and cannot leave any empty value, the nearest to an empty value that I found is `#{''}` what means "Empty String with no quotes", an empty value, but is added to the CSS.

Comment: `()` would be an empty list in Sass.