# Is it possible to create a loop to cycle through a map however stop at a certain index in the map ? - SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have a color theme map with five colors and I would like to create a mixin to accept a number argument which would be the stopping point. Then the mixin would execute the loop however stop the map loop when it reaches the mixin argument number.

Tried to read up on this however could not find any answers or solutions to get this to happen.

Code Example:

```
// color map
$colors: (
 "r": red,
 "b": blue,
 "g": green,
 "y": yellow,
 "o": orange,
)
```

Current Situation: The each loop keeps cycling through the map until it reaches the end. Hence it will create 5 selectors with their background-colors as the values in the map.

```
@mixin color_theme($map) {
  @each $col, $color in $map {
    &.#{$col} {
      background-color: $color;
    }
  }
}
```

Goal: To create a mixin with a loop to cycle only to a fixed number of values in the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `index` (related answer: [SASS - get map item value by item index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468351/sass-get-map-item-value-by-item-index)) to get the map index number and then use it to stop the loop at a certain number:

```
// color map
$colors: (
 "r": red,
 "b": blue,
 "g": green,
 "y": yellow,
 "o": orange
);

@mixin color_theme($map, $stop) {
  @each $col, $color in $map {
    $i: index($map, $col $color);
    @if ($i <= $stop){
      &.#{$col} {
        background-color: $color;
      }
    }
  }
}

div{
  @include color_theme($colors, 4);
}
```

Your output:

```
div.r {
  background-color: red;
}
div.b {
  background-color: blue;
}
div.g {
  background-color: green;
}
div.y {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```