# struggling with sass each output is empty

Tags: sass

I'm about to try something pretty similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380156/2309928

I've got this scss code:

```
$max-width: 95vw;
$max-height: 95vh;

$styleFactors: ("very-large": 1, "large": 0.75, "normal": 0.4, "small": 0.35);

@each $widthOrHeight in "width", "height"{

  @each $style, $factor in $styleFactors {

    $max-size: if($widthOrHeight == "width", $max-width, $max-height);
    .#{$widthOrHeight}-#{$style} {
      $style: calc(#{$max-size} * #{$factor});
    }
  }
}
```

expected output should look something like this:

```
.width-very-large{
  width: calc(95vw * 1);
}
.width-large{
  width: calc(95vw * 0.75);
}
.width-normal{
  width: calc(95vw * 0.4);
}
.width-small{
  width: calc(95vw * 0.35);
}
//...
//and same with height
```

but there is **no output at all** and I'm out of ideas why this is happening..

> theres no error or anything

[Try it out on Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/ff4e1fbc26591c11c5b85a70d874e87d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not actually apply any styles and empty styles are simply removed. If you add for instance `#{$widthOrHeight}: $style;` after `$style: calc(#{$max-size} * #{$factor});` you will see an output.

Answer (score 0):

updated [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/a22d56c585153a5ba8fdbf0c40e51eff):

fault was at line 17:

```
$max-width: 95vw;
$max-height: 95vh;

$styleFactors: ("very-large": 1, "large": 0.75, "normal": 0.4, "small": 0.35);

@each $widthOrHeight in "width", "height"{

  @each $style, $factor in $styleFactors {

    $max-size: if($widthOrHeight == "width", $max-width, $max-height);
    .#{$widthOrHeight}-#{$style} {
```

> ```
>     #{$widthOrHeight}: calc(#{$max-size} * #{$factor});
> ```

```
    }
  }
}
```